# SQFLite and Flutter data types errors

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

I'm trying to create a simple table in Flutter with [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) and I'm having trouble with data types for making one. I call the API, I get the data from the API and try to create the table and fill the the key/data types but I do it for id, title and overview (INT, TEXT, TEXT) but having trouble with the rest.. The code:

JSON from the API:

```
{
            "genre_ids": [
                28,
                878,
                53
            ],
            "id": 766507,
            "overview": "When danger threatens her camp, the fierce and highly skilled Comanche warrior Naru sets out to protect her people. But the prey she stalks turns out to be a highly evolved alien predator with a technically advanced arsenal.",
            "poster_path": "/ujr5pztc1oitbe7ViMUOilFaJ7s.jpg",
            "title": "Prey",
            "vote_average": 8.1,
        },
```

Model for the JSON data:

```
class Movies{
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? overview;
  List<int>? genreIds;
  dynamic voteAverage;
  String? posterPath;

  PopularMovies({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.overview,
    this.genreIds,
    this.voteAverage,
    this.posterPath,
  });

  PopularMovies.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    overview = json['overview'];
    genreIds = json['genre_ids'];
    voteAverage = json['vote_average'];
    posterPath = json['poster_path'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = id;
    data['title'] = title;
    data['overview'] = overview;
    data['vote_average'] = voteAverage;
    data['genre_ids'] = genreIds;
    data['poster_path'] = posterPath;
    return data;
  }
}
```

And the creating table method:

```
// Create the database and the Movies table
  initDB() async {
 
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'movies.db');

    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {},
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute('CREATE TABLE Movies('
          'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
          'title TEXT,'
          'overview TEXT,'
          'vote_average REAL,'
          'poster_path TEXT,'
          'genre_ids INT,'
          ')');
    });
  }
```

Like I said, I get the returning values of id, title and overview, but not for the rest of the 3 fields and I don't know how to solve it... I assume in the Model class I have made a mistake or something similar? Thanks in advance for any form of help.

Comment: Any particular reason why you need vote average as dynamic? Why not parse it to double, or better yet to String?

Comment: No particular reason, I can change it. What is the best way to do that, inside the Model class?

Comment: in the model change it to `String voteAverage`  in `fromJson` method to ` voteAverage = json['vote_average'] as String;` or use toString() whichever you prefer. And finally in `db.create ` use `'vote_average TEXT,'` Please tell if that works so I could post it as answer.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work..